# What algorithm does the Devise gem use to generate the authentication token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, encryption, devise

I have an app that uses the Devise authentication token mechanism to do client token authentication. I was wondering what algorithm the gem uses to generate the token itself? Is it BCrypt? MD5 etc etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is in `devise.rb`:

```
# Generate a friendly string randomically to be used as token.
def self.friendly_token
  SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')
end
```

http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise.friendly_token

Comment: Why is it replacing string characters using `.tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')`?

Comment: Just a guess, but replacing +/= is probably done to avoid potential problems with tokens in URLs, the lIO0 is probably for easier readability by humans.

Comment: The latest version on Devise is not replacing +/= anymore.

Comment: Based on this change https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/2549/files it looks like it is still replacing `+/=` by using the `urlsafe_base64` method instead.